# How to get all nearest position of selected item of gridview(or RecyclerGridview)

Tags: android, gridview, grid, logic

I am Trying to make some logic but I cant reach at the actual result.
I am use r**ecyclerview(GridLayoutManager)**.
I have grid cell like **3*3,5*5,7*7**...and so on..

bewlow is image of 3*3 grid

[image]

Now what is my situation that I need position of **All nearest cell**.

as shown in image I describe some case example below :

**case 1 :**

> Selected Cell -1
>    expected result -2,5,4

**case 2 : (as in image)**

> Selected Cell -5
>   expected result -1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9

**case 3 :**

> Selected Cell -6
>   expected result -3,5,9

So, how can I achieve dynamically for all cell box 3*3,5*5,7*7....so on

Comment: What had you tried? It should be very easy ... let selected cell be presented as (r,c) then you have to get all celles starting from (r-1, c-1) to (r+1, c+1) with exlusion of self and not existing one ... (r- row, c- column)

Comment: But sir ,  this is arraylist is 1D  suppose its size 9 then grid make 3*3  then how can i understand which no is row and wich is colum, and also its variable 5*5,7*7 and so on.. @Selvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a easy way to achieve this .not perfect , but easy.

```
public void getNeareast(int m, int choosedId) {

    if (m <= 2) {//too simple ,you can just return the right result;

        return;
    }

    int[] choose = new int[]{-m - 1, -m, -m + 1, -1, 0, +1, m - 1, m, m + 1};
    int x = choosedId / m;
    int y = choosedId % m;
    if (x == 0 || (y == 0 && x == 1)) {//no top data
        choose[0] = 0;
        choose[1] = 0;
        choose[2] = 0;
    }

    if ((x == m - 1 && y != 0) || x == m) {// no bottom data
        choose[6] = 0;
        choose[7] = 0;
        choose[8] = 0;
    }

    if (y == 1) { // no left data
        choose[0] = 0;
        choose[3] = 0;
        choose[6] = 0;
    }

    if (y == 0) {// no right data
        choose[2] = 0;
        choose[5] = 0;
        choose[8] = 0;
    }

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {//get choosed data
        if (choose[i] != 0) {
            result.add(choosedId + choose[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int i : result) {//print result;
        Log.d("biu", "biu->" + i);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is m in getNeareast();

Comment: m= 3 then its work properly ...

But can you please give me the brief description for that. its work ..

Comment: ok,the main idea is that , when m > 3 , every item you chose should have 8 items around it. 
just think about this,there is a 3 * 3 cell box.(m = 3)
if you choose 5 ,there should be 8 item around it.this is the normal situation.if you choose 1,there also should be 8 item around it,but the 1 is on the border,and 1 % 3 = 1 means the chosen item is the first column,so there  is no item on it's left, 1 / 3 = 0.333333 ,integer part is zero ,so there is no item on it's top,so you just cut off the left and top item from 8 items ,you will get the right result.other situation just like this.